# Failed to compile and run for Android with Cordova 3.5

Tags: android, cordova, visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-cordova

1. I installed the extensions and created the new project based on Installed/Templates/Other Languages/JavaScript/Muti-Device Hybrid App/Blank App (Apache Cordova)
2. I selected Android as the platform.
3. I selected Ripple - Nexus 7 (Tablet) as the debugger and pressed F5 to compile and run.
4. It errors out with the following error:  "Error 2   ENOENT, no such file or directory 'C:\Users\C.cordova\lib\android\cordova\3.5.0\VERSION'   C:\DATA\SOURCE\AllSoc\AllSoc\EXEC   1   1   AllSoc
5. The project is called AllSoc.

Does anyone have any idea how to get unstuck from here.  From all the documentation and videos I've seen, this part SHOULD just work.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The cordova platform might not have gotten fully downloaded.  Try deleting the contents of `C:\Users\C\.cordova` and then re-run your build.  And be sure to let the build go to completion - don't cancel it.  This will re-download the platform.

Comment: Hey Ellen, I have tried a manual install of Cordova, but I'll try your directions as well to see if it solves the problem.

Comment: Thanks Ellen.  Deleting the contents of the .Cordova folder and then rerunning the solution solved the problem.  I'm not sure why it didn't install properly before, but it works now.  Thanks for the advice!

Answer (score 1):

Per Ellen's (https://stackoverflow.com/users/3912411/ellen) suggestion above, I deleted the C:\Users\C.Cordova folder's contents and then reran the project.  This time around it worked as expected.